# How to correctly load data from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm new in C and I try to load data from a file to my program. My method worked for me in a similar task but not here and I don't know why. In my opinion, my code is logically correct.

Here is this part of code responsible for loading data and displaying it:

```
int q = fscanf(stale, "&d", &q); //number of lines, in the file it is a first line where this number is kept, and below it there a 5 lines with two columns of numbers
double* tab;
tab = (double*)malloc(q * 2 * sizeof(double)); //this is the array where data should be kept
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        fscanf(stale, "%lf", &tab[i * q + j]);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("%lf", tab[i * q + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: `int q = fscanf(stale, "&d", &q);` sounds like a bad idea. How do you want to use the number of lines if you override it with `scanf` return value?

Comment: In `int q = fscanf(stale, "&d", &q);`, you need to use `"%d"` and not `"&d"`, as well as not assigning the result of `fscanf()` to the variable you just set via the argument list. `int q; if (fscanf(stale, ""%d", &q) != 1) { …error… }`.

Comment: You probably mean `fscanf(stale, "%lf", &tab[i * 2 + j]);` ? And the same later in `printf`loop.

Comment: Joel Hecht, why &tab[i * 2 +j] when I thought it is i * q phrase ??

Comment: szymill00 because `tab` is like a 2 dimensional array of size q*2. Since `i` is evaluating from 0 to q-1, which corresponds to the first dimension, you must multiply it by the size of the second dimension, which is 2. If you multiply `i` by `q` the result will be out of bounds. An alternative could be `&tab[i + (j * q)]`.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `tab = (double*)malloc(q * 2 * sizeof(double));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `fscanf(stale, "%lf", &tab[i * q + j]);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: this family of functions return the number of successful `input format conversions`.   Therefore, in the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: OT:  the code assumes that each line of the input file (other than the first line) contains 2 `double` values,  That should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: OT:  You could clean up your code and save yourself some effort by declaring a struct `struct oneline { double first; double second };`  Then use the first line value to declare an array of `struct oneline tab[ q ];`  This would also allow the code to process and/or display the data one line at a time